# Laravels regex for password validation ignored on reset password

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel reset password.

Here is my validator

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'regex:/^(?=.*\d)(?=(.*\W){2})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*\s).{1,15}$/'], //, 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9!$#%]+$/'
        ]);
    }
```

I want to have at least 2 numbers, 2 special characters and 6 characters minimum (and that's not my choice :D)

But when using laravel's reset.blade.php template and after click on the link in the email, it ignores this validation and only has 8 characters minimum validation...
Any idea?

I tried adding this in ResetPasswordConfirmation whith no success ('your password must be at least 8 characters' and the regex is ignored)

```
public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'regex:/^(?=.*\d)(?=(.*\W){2})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*\s).{1,15}$/'],
        ], $this->validationErrorMessages());

        $this->broker()->validator(function ($credentials) {
            return mb_strlen($credentials['password']) >= 6;
        });
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request),
            function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.8 changed the password minimum to 8 characters.  If you want to use 6, you will need to override the default behavior by extending the `PasswordBroker` class.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#new-default-password-length

> **New Default Password Length**
> Likelihood Of Impact: High
>
> The required password length when choosing or resetting a password was changed to eight characters. You should update any validation rules or logic within your application to match this new eight character default.
>
> If you need to preserve the previous six character length or a different length, you may extend the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker` class and overwrite the  `validatePasswordWithDefaults` method with custom logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is there any way to keep the 8 characters password check from laravel but at least to add the regular expression check?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add your own validation in addition to the default validation. Also, you may want to double check your regex as it is not requiring two numbers as you indicated in your requirements: https://regex101.com/r/Oi6MH1/1  `Full match: d1f%@`